# What is the application name of Microsoft Excel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsworkspace

What is the application name of Microsoft Excel that I would use with `-[NSWorkspace fullPathForApplication:]` ?

Comment: The application name as an `NSString`. `@"Mail"`, `@"Terminal"`, `@"Excel"`, etc. Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: I don't have Excel on my computer, so I can't try to launch it. The question is: is the name MS Excel or Microsoft Excel or Excel ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's @"Microsoft Excel" (at least with office 2008):

This:

```
NSString *path = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] fullPathForApplication:@"Microsoft Excel"];
NSLog(@"path: %@", path);
```

Outputs:

```
2012-09-10 21:42:57.059 Craplet[2164:707] path: /Applications/Microsoft Office 2008/Microsoft Excel.app
```

I tried "Excel" and "MS Excel" and confirmed they return null.

Answer (score 2):

The name and path of Excel can change, as can any application's. You might want to consider launching using its bundle ID - which is com.microsoft.Excel.